# Why is Bragg diffraction small-angle for thicker layers and/or larger molecules or unit cells? And wide-angle for small or shallow crystals?

Tags: diffraction, crystals, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

It is easy to find equations that quantify this on the internet, but not an explanation as to why...

Also, does this apply to electrons and neutrons?  Or just X-ray reflection/diffraction?

Comment: you know diffraction of light on a grid or double slit? the coarser the grid, or the larger the distance of the slits, the smaller the angle,. This is exactly the same.

Comment: @trula that's an answer

Comment: I noticed that you haven't voted on, commented on, or otherwise interacted with the answer that's there already. If you need an answer with a different approach, what would that be?

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with optical laws, regardless of the wave you use.

Bragg's law gives you the angles in which there is a maximum, but it doesn't say anything about the **intensity** you will detect on them.

If you perform the calculations, you'll find out that the intensity of the maxima rises with $N^2$, but the width decreases as $1/N$.

You can check this in a simple 1D model. Consider a chain of $N$ equally spaced atoms at a distance $a$. They're indexed from $0$ to $N-1$. Any lattice vector is $R=n\cdot a$

The intensity would be the sum $S$ squared.

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-i \Delta k\cdot R}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-i \Delta k\cdot (na)}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left(e^{-i \Delta k\cdot a}\right)^n=\dfrac{e^{-i \Delta k\cdot Na}-1}{e^{-i \Delta k\cdot a}-1}$$

$$S=e^{-i \Delta k\cdot (N-1)a/2} \cdot \dfrac{\sin(N\Delta k a/2)}{\sin(\Delta k a/2)}$$

Taylor to First order yields

$$I\propto |S|^2 = 1\cdot \left| \frac{N k a/2}{k a /2 } \right|^2 \propto N^2$$

On the otehr hand, the distance between the two first minima is proportional to $1/N$, so the width of the peak decreasses with $1/N$.